# Unable to get WPF .NET 5.0 ListView items to show up in the control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, .net-5

I have a couple of `ListView` items in my application that I add items to programmatically. Unfortunately, nothing is showing up. I've now tried binding the `ItemSource` to a `List<SystemInfoItem>` list to no avail.

I've done exhaustive Internet searches to figure out how to make it work, to no avail. I haven't come up with the magical query.

Also, I'm trying to change the header background color and the foreground color for both the headers and rows.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="VnaInfoBox" Height="160" Margin="0,10,0,10" Width="400" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding VnaSysInfoItems}">
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="vnaInfoItemCol" Header="Item" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item}"/>
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="vnaInfoValueCol" Header="Value" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView>
```

Here is the code fpr the `SystemInfoItem` class:

```
public class SystemInfoItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And, here is the code where I'm adding items to the bound list:

```
VnaSysInfoItems.Add(new SystemInfoItem() { Item = "Manufacturer", Value = VnaContainer.VnaSS.Vna_IDManuf });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] I add items to programmatically.
>
> [...] I've now tried binding the `ItemSource` to a `List<SystemInfoItem>` list to no avail.

Yes, that is *expected* behavior. A `List`, `List<T>` and other collection types do not implement any mechanism to notify changes to the user interface. In other words, the user interface cannot know when you modify a collection by adding, inserting or removing items. How would it?

For collection types there is the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0) interface that signals changes to the collection using the [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged?view=net-5.0) event. The good news is, that you do not have to implement it yourself, there is already a built-in type that supports notifying collection changes using this interface. It is called [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0). Replace your `List<T>` with this type and it should work.

```
public ObservableCollection<SystemInfoItem> VnaSysInfoItems { get; }
```

The same goes for properties. As of now, changes to your item properties `Item` and `Value` will not be detected by the user interface either. There you can [implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) interface that signals changes to a property using the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public class SystemInfoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _item;
   private string _value;

   public string Item
   {
      get => _item;
      set
      {
         if (_item == value)
            return;

         _item = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public string Value
   {
      get => _value;
      set
      {
         if (_value == value)
            return;
         
         _value = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `VnaSysInfoItems` to `ObservableCollection<SystemInfoItem>`. Unlike `List<T>`, objects added to an `ObservableCollection<T>` will notify the UI.

> Also, I'm trying to change the header background color and the foreground color for both the headers and rows.

Set the `ColumnHeaderContainerStyle` of the `GridView` to change the background and foreground of the headers:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <GridViewColumn x:Name="vnaInfoItemCol" Header="Item" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item}"/>
    <GridViewColumn x:Name="vnaInfoValueCol" Header="Value" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
</GridView>
```

To change the foreground of the rows, you could set the `Foreground` property of the `ListView` control itself (like you have already done).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had already gotten it working, but not with an ObservableCollection. I'm going to post what I did to the group. One of the things I did was to include a ListView.View around the GridView and added a DataTemplate to the GridViewColumns to set the binding to the class properties.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @mm8 and @thatguy for the correct alternatives!

Obviously, not using MVVM is bad, however, I am porting an existing complex test and measurement application from WinForms to WPF .NET 5.0, so I need to implement the first port with the mechanisms I have available from the old version so that I have a higher degree of likelihood that it will all work to get the new version out. I will be going back in after the first release of the WPF version and implementing MVVM. It's available in some places, but not throughout the App.

I ended up figuring out a solution as follows:

1. I added a ListView.View to the ListView and DataTemplate to each of the GridViewColumns:

   ```
               <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="VnaInfoBox" Height="160" Margin="0,10,0,10" Width="400" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent">
                   <ListView.View>
                       <GridView>
                           <GridViewColumn Header="Item" Width="150">
                               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                       <ContentControl Content="{Binding Item}" />
                                   </DataTemplate>
                               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           </GridViewColumn>
                           <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="240" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}">
                               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                       <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}" />
                                   </DataTemplate>
                               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           </GridViewColumn>
                       </GridView>
                   </ListView.View>
               </ListView>
   ```
2. I used a List that is built at runtime as the items in the ListView change and assign to the ListView.ItemsSource:

   ```
        // Create the VnaInfoBox data source
        List<SystemInfoItem> vnaInfo = new List<SystemInfoItem>();

         vnaInfo.Add(new SystemInfoItem() { Item = "Manufacturer", Value = "Ford" });
         vnaInfo.Add(new SystemInfoItem() { Item = "Model", Value = "Model A" });
         vnaInfo.Add(new SystemInfoItem() { Item = "Serial #", Value = "23456" });
         vnaInfo.Add(new SystemInfoItem() { Item = "Version", Value = "3.4" });
         vnaInfo.Add(new SystemInfoItem() { Item = "Options", Value = "Convertable" });

         VnaInfoBox.ItemsSource = vnaInfo;
   ```